# google.maps.geometry.spherical error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having some troubles using the geometry at google maps. I am getting the following error:
"Unable to get property 'spherical' of undefined or null reference."

This is some code from w3c with some additions of mine.

```
var x=new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916);
var stavanger=new google.maps.LatLng(58.983991,5.734863);
var amsterdam=new google.maps.LatLng(52.395715,4.888916);
var london=new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850);
function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:x,
  zoom:4,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
var myTrip=[stavanger,amsterdam,london];
var flightPath=new google.maps.Polyline({
    path:myTrip,
    strokeColor:"#0000FF",
    strokeOpacity:0.8,
    strokeWeight:2
    });
flightPath.setMap(map);

try{
    var markerpos = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(flightPath.getAt(0), flightPath.getAt(1), .5);
    // also tried //
    //var Spherical = google.maps.geometry.spherical;
    //var markerpos = Spherical.interpolate(flightPath.getAt(0), flightPath.getAt(1), .5);
    //var markerpos = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(amsterdam, london, .5);
}
catch(ex){alert(ex);}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: markerpos,
    map: map,  clickable: false
});
}
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: Did you load the geometry library?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Are you loading the [correct library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries) with the `libraries=` parameter?

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this problem was driving me crazy. I though that Google Maps has all the tools in "maps.googleapis.com/maps/api" and I did not realize that this library is not included by default as they said under "Overview" section in the API site (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry). I miss these kind of details when I don't know what I am looking for. It has to be added as "&libraries=geometry" as you say.

Comment: I know this is an older answer but you may want to update it to remove &sensor=false as that is not longer a required (or supported) parameter.

Comment: If you need to use both `places` and `geometry` libraries, (for geocoding and map work), separate the two with an unencoded comma in the libraries parameter like so: `.../maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&libraries=places,geometry&key=...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `@googlemaps/js-api-loader`, include it like this instead

```js
const loader = new Loader({
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxx",
  version: "weekly",
  libraries: ["geometry"], // additional libraries
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import libraries modules and then auth key module.
I think here the problem is at the time of executing library functions importing  library modules is not completed.
If you import auth key module first what happened is immediately it calls the initialize() method by the time library modules loading is not completed.
So you need to import library modules first and then auth module.