# How can google.maps.geometry be undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, asynchronous, requirejs

I'm writing a JavaScript application using the Google Maps Javascript API v3 and RequireJS. I wrote a little wrapper for gmaps in order to get the dependencies right:

```
define('gmaps', ['goog!maps,3.9,packages:[geometry],language:de,other_params:sensor=false&channel=...&client=...'],
function(){
    return window.google.maps;
});
```

This works perfectly fine in most of the cases, even after minifying the code using the optimizer. However, sometimes I get an error saying `gmaps.geometry is undefined` in a module that has `gmaps` as a dependency and tries to calculate a distance:

```
define(['gmaps'], function(gmaps) {
    return {
        ...
        calcDistance: function(target) {
            var position = this.getPosition();
            var distance = gmaps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
                new gmaps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude),
                new gmaps.LatLng(target.latitude, target.longitude)
            );
            return (distance / 1000).toFixed(2);
        }
    }
});
```

This only happens if I try to execute `calcDistance` right after the page and the required data has loaded and only sometimes. I guess this is some problem with the async loading of gmaps, but I don't fully understand it. How can gmaps be defined but gmaps.geometry be undefined? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`packages:[geometry]` doesn't seem to work like I thought it would, so geometry wasn't loaded at all. Google seems to internally load geometry at some point, so my code for distance calculation worked in most cases. I fixed the problem by changing the define call of my `gmaps` module to:

```
define('gmaps', ['goog!maps,3.9,language:de,other_params:libraries=geometry&sensor=false&channel=...&client=...'],
function(){
    return window.google.maps;
});
```

Answer (score 17):

It seems you are not loading the correct library. Just append `&libraries=geometry` in the library url.

Check this
[google.maps.geometry.spherical error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226053/google-maps-geometry-spherical-error#answer-15226237)

Comment: i've got two pages that both append "?libraries=geometry" to the URL... one of them works, the other one always throws this error. The one that was throwing the error lacked "&sensor=<value>".  I added that and it started work. (I thought sensor= was depreciated!)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in my situation I see that geometry libraries is not available at the initialization. I don't know why. But it became defined after some time. So I resolve the problem using a wait function.

```
setTimeout(waitForGeometryLibraries, 250);  

function waitForGeometryLibraries(){
    if(typeof google.maps.geometry !== "undefined"){
     // code using geometry library
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(waitForGeometryLibraries, 250);
    }
}
```