# Google Maps - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spherical')

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-cloud-platform

i wanna scroll to closet marker after a search. Console.log shows for pins[i] = (50.296322, 9.112082) und event (50.937531, 6.9602786).
i tried many but always get: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spherical')

```
function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap){
var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status){
    if (status === 'OK') { 
        function find_closest_marker(event){
            var distances = [];
            var closest = -1;
            for(i = 0; i < pins.length; i++){
                var d = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pins[i].position, event);
                distances[i] = d;
                if (closest == -1 || d < distances[closest]){
                    closest = i;
                }
            }
            resultsMap.setCenter(pins[closest].position);
        } 
        find_closest_marker(results[0].geometry.location);          
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: You haven't included the geometry library.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226053/google-maps-geometry-spherical-error

Answer (score 11):

http**s**://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=somesecrectkey&**libraries=geometry**&callback=initMap

Thank you for your hint, it is working now.

Comment: For those who are working with @react-google-maps/api

You can do that:

```js
 const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: 'google-map-script',
    googleMapsApiKey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`,
    libraries: ['geometry'],
  })
```